# How do I make the star ratings retain the value when I edit a review?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, raty

I'm using the jquery raty star rating system and it worked. Except that when I edit a review for example that has 4 stars, the edit page shows 0 stars. Should this how the jquery raty behaves?

Or is there a way that when I edit that review, the edit page will still retain the 4 stars but still can edit?

This is my code for edit page:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@book, @review]) do |f| %>
    <div id="rating-form">
        <label>Rating</label>
    </div>
    <%= f.input :comment %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>


<script>
    $('#rating-form').raty({
        path: '/assets/',
        scoreName: 'review[rating]'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: First, you can do this: review.surf_school = surf_school
        review.user = current_user

Comment: What line should I edit?

Comment: I don't see the problem here. Can you paste the posted params please ? `puts params.inspect`

Comment: I don't have that code.

Comment: just put puts params.inspect at the top of your method create :).

Comment: you mean def create puts params.inspect end ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102463/discussion-between-terry-raimondo-and-jeramae-bohol).

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add an option.
Try this:

```
 $('#div-rating').raty({
    path: '/assets/',
    scoreName: 'review[rating]',
    score: @review.rating
 });
```

You can read the documentation here to know the list of options:
https://github.com/wbotelhos/raty#options

Comment: Yes exactly, it should return the rating. If not, you have to check why it is not saving in database

Comment: But before I used the raty, it retained the rating.

Comment: First, try to set a @review.rating to 3 or 4 in your rails c and see if it is visually correct when you try to edit. If you want to know why it is not saving, print the post params you send to your controller

Comment: How is the JS picking up `@review`?

Answer (score 1):

you need to enter the following- score: <%= @review.rating %>. It worked for me. :)

```
<script>
    $('#rating-form').raty({
        path: '/assets/',
        scoreName: 'review[rating]',
        score: <%= @review.rating %>
    });
</script>
```